# Launching multiple instances of same ROS node (with different names)

Tags: mavlink, roslaunch, mavros, namespace, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is in simulating two independent different robots in Gazebo: Copter and Rover with same mavros functionality. (Two independent instances of mavros would do great) Can two instances of mavros nodes be run using different names?

So, I tried to call mavros and the problem turned out to be "A new node registered with same name" which terminates Gazebo. To avoid this problem, I have tried to rename node-calls and the attempts include the following mentioned below.

```
<node ns="copter" pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros">
<node ns="rover" pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros">
```

**1.** Using namespaces as shown above; This still registers the node name as "/mavros" instead of "/copter/mavros" and "/rover/mavros"

**2.** Coding separate mavros_node codes for copter and rover instead of [mavros_node.cpp](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/src/mavros_node.cpp). The modified version contains the lines shown below.

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "mavros_copter"); //In mavros_node_copter.cpp

ros::init(argc, argv, "mavros_rover"); //In mavros_node_rover.cpp
```

mavros_node.cpp, mavros_node_copter.cpp and mavros_node_rover.cpp source files are all placed in the same original folder. The entire package is then compiled with catkin_make. But, even then, using "mavros_copter" and "mavros_rover" as node name won't work with ROS Service properly while using "mavros" works.

`<node pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros">` is the original code in launch file which works.

type="mavros_node_copter" name="mavros" (works)

type="mavros_node_copter" name="mavros_copter" (doesn't work)

**3.** I tried rqt_graph and this is the most confusing part in the software simulation. mavros node is shown as an independent node. [I tried to assess how mavros is interacting with Gazebo and where how that is getting called and rqt_graph doesn't provide that information](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9GEXq3wS5JMc2Uwb2p1UXlIQVk/view?usp=sharing) (even for original code which works).

[image]

**4.** [Remapping nodes is not possible using roslaunch while command-line options like rosrun can be used.](http://answers.ros.org/question/198873/how-to-changeremap-ros-node-name-in-launch-file/)
I even tried `_name:="something"` [in command line](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/issues/279) along with roslaunch; But, that does not seem to work. (Original name is retained somehow)

Can you please let me know how multiple instances of same node can be run? (Optional: It will be great if you let me know how mavros is interacting with Gazebo)

Any help will be **greatly, gratefully and whole-heartedly** appreciated. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Prasad N R

Reference question: [Multiple robots in ROS Gazebo SITL with separate MAVlink/MAVproxy codes](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10898/multiple-robots-in-ros-gazebo-sitl-with-separate-mavlink-mavproxy-codes)

[copter_circuit](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82582a88ecf5f2030f3d2853727d3f96) -> [apm_sitl_copter](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8bc1fca3a67e8868e26a1b2bde96665) & [copter_circuit.world](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30511e7d4777cfd31562f71fcc2e7cb6) -> [node_copter](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f4543cbfbc461c4c0e8545f993c4f97e)

[rover_circuit1](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2f7b67decc7e6a84049a594f33427d0) -> [apm_sitl_rover](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc0bbdcca59c3626a3f04a594e3b5fa3) & [rover_circuit1.world (.so plugin)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f8db63356b2f6d26a86727992ed2ea2) -> [node_rover](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1edb891f816c61235f627c4da2118aa4)

[Output of roswtf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8bb8272c56dde225fd45bc36c5f947ef) , [launch commands](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e678f3222a73632284d32b7cc56b698) , [CMakeLists.txt](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/514fe3e77815c5e6be64b42f0ae8a2fe) and the original folder structure can be found in [Google Drive (uploaded sometime ago)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9GEXq3wS5JManpBZzFlc3NWSUE?usp=sharing).

Can you please let me know if I should create new packages? (namely mavros_copter and mavros_rover and guidance on that will be gratefully appreciated)

[A relatively small video has been made regarding the same.](https://vimeo.com/191208613)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247783/launching-multiple-instances-of-same-ros-node-(with-different-names)/) by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-11**:
Post exact launch code at [gist](http://gist.github.com). [Cape-posty error](http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0260/)?

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-11**:
Use http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group (place node inside).

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-11**:
**2:** Did you edit CMakeLists.txt? But that wrong approach anyway...

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-11**:
**3:** What you expect? Use `rosnode` to verify.

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-11**:
**4:** What you try to remap??? Remap change topic or service name, not node.
And again: `__name`, not `_name`!

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-11-11**:
@vooon , Thanks for that excellent clarification; If you find difficulty, I will upload on Github (multiple git init required) Trying __name and rosnode ; Thank you so much and I consider this an opportunity to thank you for excellent contributions to robotic softwares.

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-11-11**:
@vooon and viewers, you are humbly requested to let me know the mistake; "mavros_copter" node ( = "mavros" ) doesn't work like "mavros" (with __name:= override or directly using in launch file) [What files that I should modify?](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5672b3a9298df273e5e4069ed2f74d25)

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-11-11**:
The output of rosnode info is too cryptic to understand and SearchMonkey returns nothing when I search for "mavros" in files (except mavros_node.cpp). I am ready to help with documentation on mavros once this research is finished. (I really wish to finish this soon and hope to contribute more)

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-13**:
In your gist, i see that node name is changed `/mavros_copter`, SetMode obviously fails because it try to use `/mavros`. https://github.com/erlerobot/ros_erle_takeoff_land/blob/master/src/main.cpp

You need to use remap for all services.

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2016-11-13**:
Another way — edit erlerobot's node to remove `/` from beginning of topic (service) name.
Place both mavros and that node into same namespace.

```
<group ns="copter">
    <include file="$(find mavros)/launch/apm.launch">
    </include>
    <include file="...." />
</group>
```

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-11-13**:
@vooon , **Hats off** and thanks for your efforts; almost like "God of software", you solved it. This is the proper answer; So amazing. I solved this with (no private parameter needed) "/mavros_copter/..." which **isn't** filesystem that I was searching for in "/home" and "/usr" and compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using roslaunch to rename nodes should work, and is the correct way to do this.

The sample launch file that you posted appears to have a typo (both lines are the same)

You can put each node in a separate namespace:

```
<node ns="copter" pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros"/>
<node ns="rover" pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros"/>
```

Or you can avoid namespaces and just give them different names:

```
<node pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros_copter"/>
<node pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros_rover"/>
```

If you're using `<include>` tags in roslaunch, you can also push all of the nodes in that launch file into a namespace with the `ns` parameter:

```
<include ns="copter" file="$(find mavros)/launch/node.launch">
  <arg name="pluginlists_yaml" value="$(find mavros)/launch/apm_pluginlists.yaml" />
  <arg name="config_yaml" value="$(find mavros)/launch/apm_config.yaml" />
  <arg name="fcu_url" value="$(arg fcu_url/copter)" />
  <arg name="gcs_url" value="$(arg gcs_url/copter)" />
  <arg name="tgt_system" value="$(arg tgt_system/copter)" />
  <arg name="tgt_component" value="$(arg tgt_component/copter)" />
  <arg name="log_output" value="$(arg log_output/copter)" />
</include>

<include ns="rover" file="$(find mavros)/launch/node.launch">
  <arg name="pluginlists_yaml" value="$(find mavros)/launch/apm_pluginlists.yaml" />
  <arg name="config_yaml" value="$(find mavros)/launch/apm_config.yaml" />
  <arg name="fcu_url" value="$(arg fcu_url/rover)" />
  <arg name="gcs_url" value="$(arg gcs_url/rover)" />
  <arg name="tgt_system" value="$(arg tgt_system/rover)" />
  <arg name="tgt_component" value="$(arg tgt_component/rover)" />
  <arg name="log_output" value="$(arg log_output/rover)" />
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PrasadNR](https://answers.ros.org/users/28296/prasadnr/) on 2016-11-11**:
Fixed that typo :) @ahendrix I think we both are close to the solution. You are humbly requested to let me know. Thanks! (video has been made as mentioned in question https://vimeo.com/191208613) roslaunch both copter and rover in one launch has flaws as mentioned in reference question. (no chars)